# contrasts with zero-inflated glmmTMB

Tags: emmeans, glmmtmb

I'm running a zero-inflated `glmmTMB` model. I'm interested in doing pairwise comparisons between different factor levels for both the conditional and the zero-inflation components. The conditional part, I can easily do with the usual `emmeans` approach. I've been trying to use the (relatively) newly minted `glmmTMB:::emm_basis.glmmTMB`, but can't figure out some of the arguments that the function takes, and can't find examples...

Here's a toy example of where I'm at currently. I specifically added a `poly()` component to the model - my full model has both `poly()` and `ns()`, so need to figure out how these work here.

So here are the questions: 1) Do I have the `trms` argument provided correctly? 2) What are the `xlev` and `grid` arguments that the `emm_basis.glmmTMB` function needs?

```
library(glmmTMB)

data(Salamanders)
mod <- glmmTMB(count ~ spp + mined + poly(cover, 2) + (1|site), zi=~spp + mined, Salamanders, 
   family=nbinom2)

tt <- y ~ spp + mined + poly(cover, 2)
tt <- delete.response(terms(tt))

glmmTMB:::emm_basis.glmmTMB(mod,  trms = tt)
```

Thanks so much for any thoughts!

Comment: `emm_basis` methods are part of the support structure for the **emmeans** package. They are not meant to be called directly by users. Instead, use something like `library(emmeans); emmeans(mod, "spp")`

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood the  [package documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmmTMB/glmmTMB.pdf) then, as it says "it may be
necessary to refer to private versions of methods, e.g. glmmTMB:::Anova.glmmTMB(model,...)". It does seem to work in a straightforward manner using just `emmeans`. Thanks so much! If you make this into an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: I guess one comment is that when run for `component = "zi"`, the `emmeans` says "Results are given on the log (not the response) scale" - should it not say "logit" instead? The values are indeed on the logit scale (I checked manually), but the comment gave me a pause.

Comment: See my answer. I did *not* observe an issue with the wrong link function for the `"zi"` component.

Comment: Ah, good to know. My version of `emmeans` is probably new enough to run this correctly, but old enough to have the weird link note. Thank you for all the support!

Comment: Actually that code is in glmmTMB not emmeans. I think it must have been some other error that led to that anomaly. I bet if you try it again, it will work right.

Comment: I tried right after reading your comment and before posting mine, and it definitely said "log scale" despite providing results on the logit scale, which is correct. But I still haven't updated to a new version, so yeah...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The functions `emm_basis()` and `recover_data()` are support functions for the **emmeans** package, with methods for many different model classes including `glmmTMB`. Those functions are not meant to be called by the user -- and that is why they are registered as methods rather than being exported.

Rather, just call `emmeans()` or other functions in the **emmeans** package, and those methods will be used as needed.

In the case of `glmmTMB` objects, there is an optional argument `component` that may be included in the `emmeans()` call. In your example:

```
> emmeans(mod, ~spp, component = "cond")
 spp   emmean    SE  df lower.CL upper.CL
 GP     0.440 0.225 624 -0.00146    0.881
 PR    -0.382 0.483 624 -1.32983    0.566
 DM     0.596 0.203 624  0.19723    0.994
 EC-A   0.145 0.327 624 -0.49699    0.787
 EC-L   0.991 0.231 624  0.53814    1.445
 DES-L  1.009 0.188 624  0.64015    1.379
 DF     0.332 0.217 624 -0.09448    0.758

Results are averaged over the levels of: mined 
Results are given on the log (not the response) scale. 
Confidence level used: 0.95
```

(We actually didn't need to include `component`, because the default is `cond`.) These results are on the log scale as a result of the `nbinom2` family used in fitting the conditional part of the model. You can see these results on the response scale by specifying `type`:

```
> emmeans(mod, ~spp, type = "response")
 spp   response    SE  df lower.CL upper.CL
 GP       1.553 0.349 624    0.999     2.41
 PR       0.682 0.329 624    0.265     1.76
 DM       1.814 0.368 624    1.218     2.70
 EC-A     1.156 0.378 624    0.608     2.20
 EC-L     2.695 0.622 624    1.713     4.24
 DES-L    2.744 0.516 624    1.897     3.97
 DF       1.394 0.303 624    0.910     2.13

Results are averaged over the levels of: mined 
Confidence level used: 0.95 
Intervals are back-transformed from the log scale
```

You can see the zero-inflated part of the model via `compoenent = "zi"`:

```
> emmeans(mod, ~spp, component = "zi", type = "response")
 spp   response     SE  df lower.CL upper.CL
 GP       0.455 0.1064 624   0.2646    0.660
 PR       0.763 0.1406 624   0.4115    0.937
 DM       0.273 0.1128 624   0.1097    0.534
 EC-A     0.719 0.1020 624   0.4870    0.873
 EC-L     0.365 0.1085 624   0.1864    0.590
 DES-L    0.278 0.0989 624   0.1275    0.503
 DF       0.132 0.1150 624   0.0207    0.522

Results are averaged over the levels of: mined 
Confidence level used: 0.95 
Intervals are back-transformed from the logit scale
```

At this time, it doesn't appear to be possible to estimate the actual mean responses (1 - zi)*(cond mean); that's useful, but pretty messy because it entails combining the two components.